# How do I set up a wpf projects for visual studio? (premake5)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, premake

I am working on a game engine right now. I am planning to use WPF as our UI for our level editor. I am trying to create a solution file with multiple projects in it. I have managed to create 2 projects ("shared library", "WindowsApp").

Is there any sample premake5 lua script out there how add/create a WPF projects to my sln?

Edited:
Sorry I forgot to mention about premake. How to create wpf project with premake.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a blank solution and add new projects to it.
In the "New Project" window you can filter out the WPF template projects by typing "wpf" in the upper-right search box.

More info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546958(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention. I mean how to create a wpf project with premake

Answer (score 0):

by trying and error, i found the solution.

```
project "VoxelEngine_Editor"
  targetname "WPFProject"
  location "../WPFProject/"
  language "C#"
  flags { "WPF" }
  objdir "../obj"
  kind "SharedLib"

  files{ wpffiles }   -- source files
  links ("Microsoft.Csharp")
  links ("PresentationCore")
  links ("PresentationFramework")
links ("System")
links ("System.Core")
links ("System.Data")
links ("System.Data.DataSetExtensions")
links ("System.Xmal")
links ("System.Xml")
links ("System.Xml.Linq")
```